# Как нарисовать половину окружности с помощью CSS или SVG

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Я ищу способ нарисовать нижнюю часть этого круга с помощью `CSS` или `SVG`.

Мне нужно сделать дополнительный сегмент чуть меньше половины окружности.
Это, вероятно, невозможно реализовать на  чистом `CSS`, но SVG-решение сложно для меня.

Ниже на картинке, что я хочу получить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```html
<svg class="pie">
  <circle cx="115" cy="115" r="110"></circle>
  <path d="M115,115 L115,5 A110,110 1 0,1 225,115 z"></path>
</svg>
```

Перевод вопроса: [Draw half circle with CSS or SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682973/draw-half-circle-with-css-or-svg/27683031#27683031) @[parliament](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267778/parliament)

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682973/draw-half-circle-with-css-or-svg/27683031#27683031

Comment: Вопрос и ответ может показаться слишком простым для ruSO. Но я выбрал его, потому что видел и вижу, как часто задается этот вопрос в сети, поэтому счёл полезным добавить его в русскоязычную базу данных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самый лёгкий способ на SVG

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

svg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="120px" height="50px">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
<svg width="120px" height="50px">
<circle cx="50" cy="0" r="50"/>
</svg>
<svg width="50px" height="120px">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
<svg width="50px" height="120px">
<circle cx="0" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
<svg   viewBox="0 0 1000 400">
 <path id="circle" d="M10,0Q500,400 1000,0" />
</svg>
```

Это просто отграничить размер самого SVG

Answer (score 4):

Я наверно не понял задачу, потому что мне ответ кажется слишком простым...

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(orange 65%, darkorange 65%);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 65%, darkorange 65%);
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(orange 65%, transparent 65%);
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateY(-65%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 65%, darkorange 65%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: всегда только приветствую активность в решении одного вопроса разными способами. Благодарю +

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы не использовать два элемента `path` с помощью команды `arc`?

```html
<svg width="135" height="135">
  <path d="M125,85 a60,60 0 1,0 -115,0" fill="#E79A16" /><!--Top Half-->
  <path d="M10,85 a60,60 0 0,0 115,0" fill="#D78500" /><!--Bottom Half-->
</svg>
```

Вы можете легко их разделить.

```html
<svg width="135" height="135">
  <path d="M125,80 a60,60 0 1,0 -115,0" fill="#E79A16" /><!--Top Half-->
</svg>
<svg width="135" height="135">
  <path d="M10,80 a60,60 0 0,0 115,0" fill="#D78500" /><!--Bottom Half-->
</svg>
<svg width="135" height="135">
  <path d="M10,0 a60,60 0 0,0 115,0" fill="#D78500" /><!--Bottom Half-->
</svg>
```

Перевод ответа: [Draw half circle with CSS or SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27682973/draw-half-circle-with-css-or-svg/27683031#27683031) @[chipChocolate.py](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3905567/chipchocolate-py)

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете сделать это с помощью `CSS`:

```css
.partial-circle {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.partial-circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.partial-circle.top {
  height: 80px;
}
.partial-circle.bottom {
  height: 20px;
}
.partial-circle.top:before {
  top: 0;
  background: #E19B21;
}
.partial-circle.bottom:before {
  bottom: 0;
  background: #D08707;
}
```

```html
<div class="partial-circle top"></div>
<div class="partial-circle bottom"></div>
```

Перевод ответа: [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1529630/oriol)